# Ansible - Getting VSphere VM facts not printing

Tags: ansible, vsphere, ansible-facts

Am running ansible 1.9.1 and here's my playbook. The problem is that the playbook runs without any hickups but just doesnt return the VM facts as expected.

```
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  user: jenkins
  sudo: false
  gather_facts: false
  serial: 1

  tasks:
  - vsphere_guest:
      vcenter_hostname: vcenter.local
      username: user
      password: pass
      guest: vm1
      vmware_guest_facts: yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your playbook with -vvv to see the output.

Comment: Thank you for that. I can see the VM details.